# How to run another batch script with different privilege?

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a batch script as Administrator which, in turn, starts another batch script (start "title" /b /wait), but with current user's privilege.
Is this possible? What's the best way to do it?
Or how can I get the current logged in user name?

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is `runas` - this command runs batchfile with the domain and username of the currently logged in user (you could also hardcode the domain and username if you wanted a specific user):

```
runas /noprofile /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% C:\batchfile.bat
```

The `runas` command requires an external program as the last argument so it doesn't handle built in commands like dir or copy.  But you can run a built in command like copy with:

```
runas /noprofile /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% "cmd /c copy C:\source.txt C:\dest.txt"
```

You can also run things as Administrator like this:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator "cmd /c copy C:\file.txt C:\Windows\System"
```

Here is some more info:

https://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-runas-command-prompt/